# Why does the second input textfield in material component not working?

Tags: angular, material-design, material-components-web

I have used material component input in my website. I create two the same input. Here is all my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<body>
    <div class="information">
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                    <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="first">First</span>
                </span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="first">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                    <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="second">Second</span>
                </span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="second">
        </label>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
    </script>
</body>
```

But just my first input is working properly (the label move to top when I click on). And the second seemd to not have the same effect like that:

[image: my result]

What is problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));` only applying to only one elament.

So i modified the code to make two of the inputs to apply the script as shown below

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<body>
    <div class="information">
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-test1 mdc-text-field--outlined">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                    <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="first">First</span>
                </span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="first">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-test2 mdc-text-field--outlined">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                    <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="second">Second</span>
                </span>
                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="second">
        </label>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-test1'));
        mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-test2'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of `document.querySelector()`. See example [here](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/importing-js).

Answer (score 0):

I use querySelectorAll and a custom foreach method:

```
// forEach method, could be shipped as part of an Object Literal/Module
let forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); // passes back stuff we need
    }
};

// mdc_textFields:
let mdc_textFields = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field');
forEach(mdc_textFields, function (index, value) {
    return new mdc.textField.MDCTextField(value);
});
```